# Unable to get desired data with cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am new in **Cheerio js** just want to iterate a specific **li** from the website **li** looks like the following

```
<li class="webcam">
    <a href="/en/webcam/italia/lazio/roma/roma-colosseo.html">
        <span class="inner-wrapper">
            <span class="img-wrapper"><span class="label label-info lb_sm" style="position:absolute;">World
                    Wonder</span>
                <img src="https://static.skylinewebcams.com/live1151.jpg"
                    data-original="https://static.skylinewebcams.com/live1151.jpg" alt="Italy - Rome - Colosseum"
                    class="lazy" style="display: inline;" width="318">
            </span>
            <span class="title">Italy - Rome - Colosseum</span>
            <span class="description">Rome, view of the Colosseum and the ruins of the gladiator gymnasium</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to get `href` from `a` tag, `data-original` from `img` tag and `.title` from `span` tag.

Here is what I tried so far but didn't get any success,
this is the example of finding only with specific tag,
I didn't know how to find all my required thing in one go using cheerio.

```
request(url, (err, body) => {
  if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
  $ = cheerio.load(body);

  links = $('img[class=lazy]'); //jquery get all hyperlinks
  $(links).each(function (i, link) {
     console.log(i, link.attribs.alt);
     console.log(i, link.attribs.data-original);
  });
})
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate the `li`s not the `img`s:

```
let data = $('li.webcam').get().map(li => {
  return {
    href: $(li) .find('a').attr('href'),
    'data-original': $(li).find('img').attr('data-original'),
    title: $(li).find('span.title').text() 
  }
})
```